# sql/db transaction not rolling back properly with ms sql

Tags: sql-server-2008, go, transactions, gorp

So I can't get too specific, but I think what I can tell you will be enough to figure this out. First I'm using gorp to set things up and get the transaction. I am using the `github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb` driver.

Then I run through a series of operations and if of them fails I `rollback` and if all have success I `commit`. The problem is that it's only rolling back the statement that failed and not the rest of the operations. Am I wrong that this is not how that is suppose to work?

Here is some rough psudocode to give you a better idea of what I'm talking about:

```
trans,err := dbmap.Begin()
//assume all errors are received and checked before continuing
id := trans.Exec("insert thing") //successful, persists after rollback 
thing := trans.Select("Select thing") //successful
trans.Exec("update other_thing with thing") //successful, persists after rollback
newthing := trans.Exec("insert new_thing with thing") //fails, rollsback
if err != nil{
   trans.Rollback() //No errors
   return
}
trans.Commit()
```

Am I wrong that that should `rollback` everything since `dbmap.Begin()`? Is this a bug in the driver implementation? Any and all help is GREATLY welcome. Thanks!

**Update**

Tested https://play.golang.org/p/0L3Vgk8C_F and it worked so I'm guessing that means it something to do with gorp. I'm using the v1 branch since this will be production soon and so stability is key. I'll be picking through it, but it looks like it's just wrapping it lightly.

Comment: Did you try looking at the trace using the sql profiler from the SQL management tools suite? I'd check if the expected commands are really sent over the wire.

Comment: The next thing to check is to verify the autocommit mode is not somehow gets enabled as otherwise every single command you send is essentially in a separate transaction.

Comment: And a crucial bit of information is missing: what are you using as the driver? `gorp` IUUC is a mapper, not an access layer.

Comment: You are, of course, right about the driver. I had meant to include it in the info, but forgot I guess. `github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb` I'll also add it to the OP.

Comment: Can you try this example on `MSSQL 2008` https://play.golang.org/p/0L3Vgk8C_F ? That works for me, but using `MSSQL 2012`. If it works, so there is some errors in `gorp` package. If not, maybe bug in `github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb` with `MSSQL 2008`

Comment: So can you try example?

Comment: I've just tested my example on MSSQL 2008 and it works

Comment: I just tried that example and it worked, so I'm guessing that means the problem is on gorp's side. Anyone have any info that may be helpful? I'm about to dig through the gorp transaction code, but yeah... (PS sorry for the delay in responding, we are in a crazy tight crunch time right now)

Answer (score 2):

Check you don't have autocomit enabled. Many command line tools, uis and even drivers enable it by default

Comment: That makes a TON of sense, but I can't find anything about autocommit in either of the projects involved: https://github.com/go-gorp/gorp/tree/v1 for my wrapper and https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb for the driver itself. Is there any other term they may call it by? I also just searched for commit, but none of that led to anything either. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to this( I read just a few lines) https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187878(v=sql.105).aspx

autocommit seems to be ON by defauly, that leads me to conclusion that if the author of go-mssqldb didn't implement on/off for this feature its ON.

You can toggle it yourself just search for SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS

Comment: "A connection to an instance of the Database Engine operates in autocommit mode until a BEGIN TRANSACTION statement starts an explicit transaction, or implicit transaction is set on. When the explicit transaction is committed or rolled back, or when implicit transaction mode is turned off, the connection returns to autocommit mode." Good thought, but that makes me think, that's not it. :-(